# APK update kills foreground service - reported as a crash

Tags: android, service

The scenario is:

- My app is running with an active foreground service.
- I choose to re-install or upgrade my app.
- The system will force quit the *old* app, including the service.
- **The system will now report that my service crashed.**
- The system *replaces* the app.
- My *new* app is installed and can get up and running, starting the foreground service again as needed.

### Is there any way to avoid the system reporting a crash when it kills a foregrounded service?

The running app never receives any *exit hook* -type information and just goes away. I have no way to **stopForeground** so that the OS is not surprised by the disappearance of the service.

Is this just accepted for any foreground service? I am not Spotify or something, but I assume apps like that must run into this every now and then?

I would appreciate any expert insight into this topic and what, if anything, can be done. My enterprise app (of sorts) annoys the QA when they see a crash every upgrade.

#### Clarifying Updates:

The various PACKAGE_* intents notify an app of other apps being installed, updated, or removed. They do not tell the app being replaced that this is about to happen.

There is also a MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED intent which does tell you about being updated. But it notifies the newly installed version that the install was an update.

Comment: just wild guess: maybe `Intent#ACTION*_PACKAGE_*` can help somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have no way to stopForeground so that the OS is not surprised by the disappearance of the service.

Well you can use [ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED)

> Broadcast Action: A new version of your application has been installed
>   over an existing one. This is only sent to the application that was
>   replaced. It does not contain any additional data; to receive it, just
>   use an intent filter for this action.

**[EDIT]**

 I did a small research - what I did is,
Created one class -

```
public class InstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Timber.e("onReceive() %s", intent.getAction());
    }
}
```

Registered that receiver in manifest.xml

```
<receiver
            android:name=".receivers.InstallReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

... and when I re-install the app with same version(ran the app through ADB), broadcast gets called and here is the result in Logcat:

```
E/InstallReceiver: onReceive() android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED
```

**[EDIT 2]**

If you want to know before the app is going to be replaced, ***I guess there is no way!*** and you don't need to worry about it as if the the app is replaced, the process is going to be terminated by system. No other special things to perform!!

For more info [Follow this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47391915/is-there-any-way-to-get-notified-before-the-app-is-being-replaced-by-another/47392194#47392194)

Comment: I am already implementing MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED. It does not help with this issue though. As your quoted text states: this only notified the new app that is was installed as an update. It does allow me to check wether my app was interrupted and I should automatically start a service.

Comment: Is the receiver triggering or not? If yes, you can use it to stop your service and start it later on.

Comment: The question is specifically for the "old" app to be notified before it is killed. I know there are no adverse behavior but QA people are freaked out by the system calling is a "crash" when a foreground service is force quit.

Comment: AFAIK, There is no way!

Comment: Thanks. That has been my understanding too but I felt the pressure to confirm from more experienced Android developers.