# Is there any way to get notified before the app is being replaced by another?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, android-package-managers

I know about the [ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED) Intent action but what it do is - notifies the receiver **AFTER** the app got replaced.

But the things is - **I want to know before the app is being replaced by another.**

I tried with these actions

```
<receiver
    android:name=".receivers.InstallReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">

       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
       </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

but doesn't help!

Comment: AFAIK, Probably NO

Comment: What if I want to stop some service before the app got uninstalled? I know service will automatically killed by system but somehow It is getting crashed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know before the app is being replaced by another

That is not possible, sorry.

> What if I want to stop some service before the app got uninstalled?

When an app is replaced or removed, its process is terminated. The process will be terminated for many other reasons as well (e.g., old age, Force Stop in Settings). There should be no need to do something special for the replacement/uninstall scenario.

Comment: Hmm.. Make sense now.